# How to open a file from a URI/Uri in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to open a file from my emulator's internal storage (was trying to put it in sdcard but it put to internal storage?). I have the user choose a file, then pass that file's Uri (note the case) to a text editing activity via intent. In this activity, I've tried a few things. My current code looks like this (excuse the madness, I've been trying a LOT of things):

```
try {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        File file;
        Uri uri = Parcels.unwrap(intent.getParcelableExtra("uri"));

        URI newUri = new URI("file://"+uri.toString());
        Log.d("uri", uri.toString());
        Log.d("newUri", newUri.toString());
        file = new File(newUri);
        if (intent != null) {

            Log.d("uriPath", uri.toString());
            if (uri != null) {

                file = new File(uri.getPath());
                String text = readTextFile(file);
                if (text != null) {
                    Log.d("in if text not null", text);
                    mEditText.setText(text);
                }
//        mEditText.setText(readTextFile(file));
            }
        }
    }
    catch(URISyntaxException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

I've tried a LOT of things, with no success. I'm either getting file not found (as it's not prefixing the file with anything, just trying to load "document/primary%3Aindex.html"), or other exceptions, currently:

```
06-06 05:43:18.826 10794-10794/net.a40two.pext E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: net.a40two.pext, PID: 10794
                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.a40two.pext/net.a40two.pext.ui.EditorActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found authority in URI: file://content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3Aindex.html
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found authority in URI: file://content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3Aindex.html
                                                                 at java.io.File.checkURI(File.java:230)
                                                                 at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:175)
                                                                 at net.a40two.pext.ui.EditorActivity.onCreate(EditorActivity.java:67)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This happens even without the file:// concatenation. Most anything I can find online is either incredibly old, doesn't work, or both. Any help is sincerely appreciated.

The code in my main activity where I'm getting this URI is straight from developers.android.com:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                             Intent resultData) {
    // The ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent was sent with the request code
    // READ_REQUEST_CODE. If the request code seen here doesn't match, it's the
    // response to some other intent, and the code below shouldn't run at all.
    if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // The document selected by the user won't be returned in the intent.
        // Instead, a URI to that document will be contained in the return intent
        // provided to this method as a parameter.
        // Pull that URI using resultData.getData().
        Uri uri = null;
        if (resultData != null) {
            uri = resultData.getData();
            Log.i("onActivityResult", "Uri: " + uri.toString());

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditorActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("uri", Parcels.wrap(uri));
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an invalid [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) here, `file://content://` - you should have one or the other, not both. ( I do not know which one in this context, but the exception is a malformed URI )

Comment: @MattClark as I said above, this happens with or without the file:// prefix.

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected file scheme in URI: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3Aindex.html`

Comment: Well that URI still looks invalid. What is the physical location of the file you are trying to access? On external storage? Or was it compiled into the source directory, and distributed with the APK? Either way, you are accessing the files incorrectly.

Comment: @MattClark as said in the first sentence, it's in the emulator's internal storage. I uploaded it via Android Device Monitor. It's not included in the APK or associated with my app in any way, other than being in the same emulator. The URI I'm passing into this activity and retrieving via `Uri uri = Parcels.unwrap(intent.getParcelableExtra("uri"));` is the one returned by the Android system. I am aware I'm accessing it incorrectly. I am not aware of the correct way to do so, obviously.